# VSTO Outlook Addin How to Grab Email Addresses From to, cc and bcc Text Boxes

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, ribbon

I am working on an outlook addin project using VSTO and C#. I would like to know if there is a way to get the user entered text from the to, cc and bcc text boxes when the user clicks send. I am already familiar with the clicking send action event I just need to know about getting the text. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When `Application.ItemSend` event fires, the item beign sent will be passed as a parameter to your event handler. You can access the `MailItem.Recipients` collection to read all names and addresses.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I am having trouble with the MailItem.Recipients collection. It states to use Recipients(index), where index is the name or index number, to return a single recipient object. My instance of mailItem.Recipients is called recipients. When I enter recipients(0) I get an error stating Method name expected. I am pretty sure I have properly instantiated the collection since I have been able to use recipients.Count to to successfully retrieve the number of recipients.

Comment: All Outlook collections are 1 based, not 0.  You can also use a foreach loop to loop through all recipients.